# Terraform provider ignore order of TypeList

Tags: terraform, terraform0.12+, terraform-provider, terraform-state

I have a terraform resource with a `TypeList` field, which is modeled like this:

```
&schema.Resource{
    Schema: map[string]*schema.Schema{
        "spec": &schema.Schema{
            Description: "Specification of the resource",
            Elem: &schema.Resource{Schema: map[string]*schema.Schema{
                "custom_addons": &schema.Schema{
                    Description: "some desc",
                    Elem: &schema.Resource{Schema: map[string]*schema.Schema{
                        "depends_on": &schema.Schema{
                            Description: "some desc",
                            Elem:        &schema.Schema{Type: schema.TypeString},
                            Optional:    true,
                            Type:        schema.TypeList,
                        
                        },
                        "name": &schema.Schema{
                            Description: "some desc",
                            Optional:    true,
                            Type:        schema.TypeString,
                        }
                    }},
                    MaxItems: 0,
                    MinItems: 0,
                    Optional: true,
                    Type:     schema.TypeList,
                
                },
                -- other complex fields here --
                -- other complex fields here --
                -- other complex fields here --
            MaxItems: 1,
            MinItems: 1,
            Optional: true,
            Type:     schema.TypeList,
        },
    },
}
```

I want the "custom_addons" field to ignore any change in order of it's items. The API does not keep track of the order of items and may store the items internally in an order that is not same as the order specified in the terraform configuration file. In such cases, if we run `terraform plan` without changing anything, we see a diff that shows the order of items being changed.

I know this is the intended behaviour for `TypeList` and I should be using `TypeSet` if ordering is not important. This one field was just an example. Our terraform provider at the moment manages around ~40 resources and all of them combined we will have thousands of `TypeList` fields that should have actually been `TypeSet`. But making this change is simply not feasible for us at the moment as apart from simple DataType change, we will also need to change a lot of code to use correct type-casting (from `data.([]interface{})` to `data.(*schema.Set)`.

So I am looking for quick and generic ways to make it work with `TypeList`.  What I have tried:
I have tried `DiffSupressFunc` as [described here](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-plugin-sdk/issues/477#issuecomment-1238807249). This solution works fine if the only change to be applied is change in order as I can suppress it in that case. But in cases when there has been a change in order of items and a new item being added/edited, I cant simply suppress the diff (because a valid change has been made) and the diff shows the new valid change along with the `custom_addon` items order change.

So I explored further to see if I can do something with `CustomizeDiff` function, but looks like it only allows changing (using the `setNew` method) on `computed` fields.

How do I make this work? Is this even possible with sdkv2?

Comment: I'm afraid I can't really imagine any plausible way to implement what you want with SDKv2. That old SDK's handling of complex types is incredibly limited due to it having originally been designed for Terraform v0.11 and earlier which barely supported complex types at the language level.

Comment: Even ignoring the limitations of the legacy SDK, Terraform Core itself expects a provider to preserve the ordering of a list as written by the user in the configuration, so you can't do _exactly_ what you described regardless of which support library you use.

Comment: One possible compromise would be to design your "Read" function so that it fetches the objects from the remote API but then returns them in the same order they were in the prior state, thereby using the Terraform state to retain some information about the ordering even though the remote API doesn't. You would of course need to decide what should happen if there are objects in the remote API that didn't exist in prior state, so this isn't perfect but it would at least avoid problems for folks who don't add new objects Terraform.

Comment: (You can use `ResourceData.Get` in your read function to obtain the prior state value to correlate the API results with, as long as you do so before calling `ResourceData.Set`.)